# Weblogic deployment J2EE Deployment SPI:260101]Parameter 'moduleArchive' may not be null

Tags: weblogic, web-deployment, weblogic11g

I am trying to re-deploy an application to Weblogic 10.3.6 using command line deployment using the following,

```
 java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl myserver:7001 -user deploymyuser 
-password welcome1 -targets mytarget -name appname -redeploy 
 D:/app/deploy/app.ear -upload -remote
```

I am getting the following errors

```
<Error> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260101> <Parameter 'moduleArchive' 
may not be null.>
[J2EE Deployment SPI:260101]Parameter 'moduleArchive' may not be null.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the switch "-source" with the redeploy command:

```
java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl myserver:7001 -user deploymyuser -
password welcome1 -targets mytarget -name appname -redeploy 
-source D:/app/deploy/app.ear -upload -remote
```